# Can we set RelativeLayout or LinearLayout logic in ViewGroup derived class?

Tags: android, derived-class, viewgroup

I have an abstract class `ClassA` which derives from **ViewGroup**.

I would like to extend `ClassA` to these class :

`ClassB` with **LinearLayout** layout logic

`ClassC` with **RelativeLayout** layout logic

Is this possible ?

I didn't found how to implement default **LinearLayout** or **RelativeLayout** logic in derived method **onLayout()** and **onMeasure()**.

Is there any other solution if it's not possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be better to extend `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` directly from `ClassB` and `ClassC`. Then, you use [composition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) to enhance those classes' behavior with the `ClassA`'s logic.

Comment: Ok, but with this solution I can't use `ClassA` as parameter type to access derived-method. Not so good

Comment: Yes, you can... that's what delegation is for. By the way, in this case `ClassA` should not extend `ViewGroup`

Comment: Ok, if I understand, I can access `ClassA` methods using `ClassA` instance in `ClassB` and `ClassC`. Right ? But this is not possible to cast `ClassA` to `View`, which cause some problem with my implementation. It seems to be more complex than I was thinking

Comment: Yes, you cannot cast from `ClassA` to `View`... but you can cast from `ClassB` and `ClassC` to `View`.